# What is the equivalent datatype of SQL Server's Numeric in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server we can write data AS `Numeric(15,10)` .. what will the equivalent of this in C#?

I know that `Numeric`'s equivalent is `Decimal` but how to represent `Numeric(15,10)`?

Comment: Well `Decimal` should be good enough

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent, in that there are no built-in .NET types which allow you to specify the precision/scale explicitly as far as I'm aware. There's no *fixed*-point type like NUMERIC.

`decimal` and `double` are the common floating point types in .NET, with `decimal` implementing [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) (like NUMERIC in T-SQL) and `double` implementing [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) behaviour (like FLOAT and REAL in T-SQL). (There's `float` as well, which is a smaller binary floating point type.)

You should choose between `decimal` and `double` based on what values you're going to represent - I typically think of "man-made", artificial values (particularly money) as being appropriate for `decimal`, and continuous, natural values (such as physical dimensions) as being appropriate for `double`.

Comment: these distinctions also apply to the SQL server types - `numeric`/`decimal` are decimal floating point types, `float` and `real` are binary floating point, so you should match like for like.

Answer (score 15):

Try looking at [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) as a guide to the data type mappings. As far as the precision and length, you control that yourself using [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers depending on two questions:

1) What is something that allows you to specify the precision and scale.  Nothing.  This seems like your question, but just in case:

2) What is something that allows you to specify a decimal floating point number *exactly*.  This is indeed the Decimal type -- but the point is internal and is set to one of 2^32 positions based on the input number.  Not sure why, but only 28 values work, or 2^5 - 4..

So even though .Net allows the Decimal to look like a float, it is very different under the covers and does match the Decimal of SQLServer. Anything not a sum of distinct power of 2 values is an estimation using the normal binary floating point.  This means even something such as the number 0.1, has already lost precision.  But not with the Decimal type.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `EntityFrameWorkCore` there is a solution for this.
after defining `DbContext` in your project you can add configuration for the model as below:

```
public class ChequeEfConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Cheque>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Cheque> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(a => a.Amount).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");                 
    }
}
```

or you can use `OnModelCreating` in your `DbContext` like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Cheque>().Property(x => x.Amount)
          .IsRequired().HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
}
```

but I would recommend you to use the first one.
for more information visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: And you can also use the attribute `[Precision(18, 2)]` on the entity model property as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71114340/ef-core-6-decimal-precision-warning/71799564#71799564)