# How to map numeric to double in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to map a SQL column with numeric type to a double property without casting?

```
SQL
[Length] [numeric](15, 4) NOT NULL

C#
class Item
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent datatype of SQL Server's Numeric in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771891/what-is-the-equivalent-datatype-of-sql-servers-numeric-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done in my projects, specially for enum casting.

```cs
class Item
{
  [Column("Length")]  
  public decimal _Length {
    get => (decimal)Length;
    set => Length = (double)value;
  }

  [NotMapped]
  public double Length { get; set; }
}
```