# EF Core 6 Decimal precision warning

Tags: entity-framework-core

After upgrading to EF Core 6, I have this annoying warning here when adding a migration:

```
No store type was specified for the decimal property '{property}' on entity type '{entityType}'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values in 'OnModelCreating' using 'HasColumnType', specify precision and scale using 'HasPrecision', or configure a value converter using 'HasConversion'.
```

which is defined here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Properties/SqlServerStrings.Designer.cs

I am not sure to understand the purpose of this warning because on entities with the tag    `[Keyless]` as they do not live in the database. Also adding an attribute such as      `[Column(TypeName = "decimal(28, 6)")]` doesn't seem to clear the warning on keyless entities.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apparently there's a [new attribute for EF Core 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069510):

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

...

[Precision(18, 2)]
```

Comment: That's great thank you, indeed the requirement for HasPrecision corresponds to the tag [Precision(18, 2)] and not [Decimal(18, 2)]

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Helped me greatly!

Answer (score 2):

In your IEntityTypeConfiguration implementation you can also use .HasPrecision(int precision, int scale)

```
public class YourTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<YourType> {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<YourTyp> builder) {
        builder.ToTable("TableName");

        builder.Property(i => i.YourProperty).HasPrecision(28,6); 
    }
}
```