# Field<int> Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i have this question, i have a procedure call which is ment to return only one row.
The DB table has VARCHAR2 and NUMBERS as Data Types, amongs others.

This is my code

```
///code
DataTable table = Class.GetCUDOC( param );
if ( table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0 )
{

    lblCudoc.Text = 
        table.Rows[0].Field<string>( "CUDOC_ORIGIN" ) + "-" +
        table.Rows[0].Field<int>( "CUDOC_NUMBER" ); <-- THIS LINE PRODUCES THE ERROR
}
//more code
```

Any suggestion would help a lot, thanks!

Comment: You should choose between decimal and double. This thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771891/what-is-the-equivalent-datatype-of-sql-servers-numeric-in-c-sharp

Comment: Oracle's `NUMBER` (as I assume that's what we're talking about here) is probably going to be mapped to `decimal`. If you are only dealing with a single row, `DataTable` is rather ludicrous overhead. Consider using Dapper with `QuerySingle` -- I believe that will also be able to take care of the `int` conversion transparently, if you know `CUDOC_NUMBER` will always fit in one.

Comment: We need to know the DB vendor (Oracle?  MSSQL? mySQL?) and column type (Oracle "NUMBER"?  MSSQL "int"? Other?) to know what the appropriate C# cast should be.  My guess would be Oracle "NUMBER" => C# "double"

Comment: I forgot to mention, the DB is oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, all the Types i've tried weren't working so i did this:

table.Rows[0][ "CUDOC_NUMBER" ]